# Is there a way to select the label of the optgroup in a select tag?

Tags: html, select, optgroup

Let's say we have this select tag. Is it possible for me to select 'Swedish Cars' option that shows up in the dropdown?

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="German Cars">
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

If not, what would be a good suggestion in making something similar and so that 'Swedish Cars' is selectable?

Comment: You mean, you want this to be a multi-select control? With the possibility to select all options in an optgroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Javascript `select` might help.

First, show only `Swedish Cars`, `German Cars` etc., in one "Parent" dropdown. When a parent is selected, their children show up in a new dropdown.

Don't force the user to select a child.

This is better illustrated in this page: http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select/taxonomy - look at the very first Dropdown system...

Comment: "Don't force the user to select a child" - Why?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to give up using `SELECT` and use styled unordered lists in a drop-down replacement using JavaScript to make it behave like `SELECT`.